# Ошибочное перенаправление после входа joomla

Tags: php, joomla

При неверной авторизации на сайте (joomla 2.5.28) выкидывает на строку с ошибкой:

```
jos-Error: Представление не найдено [name, type, prefix]: login, HTML, contentView
JSite -> dispatch() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/index.php:42
JComponentHelper :: renderComponent() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/includes/application.php:194
JComponentHelper :: executeComponent() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:348
require_once() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/application/component/helper.php:380
JController -> execute() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/components/com_content/content.php:16
ContentController -> display() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:761
JController -> display() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/components/com_content/controller.php:74
JController -> getView() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:677
JError :: raiseError() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php:903
JError :: raise() @ /var/www/html/site.ru/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:251
```

Данные ошибки идут только во фронтенде, в админке все нормально. 
PHP 5.3 (то же на 5.5).

Comment: Возможно проблема в пути для логов и тмп, в configuration.php укажите корректный путь  $log_path  и $tmp_path, проблема должна исчезнуть.

Comment: пути верные указаны были, дирректории так же существуют, проблема иммет место

Comment: ошибки появляются непосредственно после неправильного ввода логина/пароля. При правильном все нормально. Если с ошибки сделать возврат назад, то переходит на верную страницу (вы ввели неправильные учетные данные....)

Comment: перенес сайт на локалку, данные ошибки ушли, вероятность появления ошибок ввиду наличия https протокола

Comment: да возможно, или проблемы с www и без....

Comment: удалял полностью .htaccess где прописаны перенаправления, та же ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Если данные действия не помогли, попробуйте закоментировать строку: 
`$this->triggerEvent('onUserLoginFailure', array((array) $response));`

в файле, строка приблизительно 774

`libraries/joomla/application/application.php`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с ошибкой. Был неверно приписан locathion при ssl настройке nginx. Проблема решена, спасибо за помощь!